# dplyr filter usage - wildcard?

Tags: r, dplyr

What's the right way to use `filter` if I don't have a data frame with named columns? For example, something similar to this.

```
c("a", "b","a") %>% filter(!="a")
```

Is there a wildcard character we can use to refer to the input of `filter`, something like

```
c("a", "b","a") %>% filter(_ != "a")
```

Comment: I would rather use `subset` if I don't deal with a data,frame e.g `c("a", "b", "a") %>% subset(. != "a")` but If you insist in using `filter` you can coerce the vector to `data.frame` (or `tbl_df`) first e.g `c("a", "b", "a") %>% data_frame %>% filter(. != "a")`

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use dplyr for this? why not just do something like:
    `x = c("a", "b", "c")

   x[x != "a"]`

Comment: The `d` in `dplyr` is for `data.frame`, every function takes a `data.frame` as its first argument. You're trying to use a screwdriver on a nail.

Comment: Yeah great point  Gregor, it looks like `subset()` is the hammer I'm after.

Answer (score 1):

with `magrittr` you can keep a similar syntax and use `extract` (it's just alias for `'['` :

```
library(magrittr)
c("a", "b","a") %>% extract(. != "a")
```

In this specific case a logical choice is `setdiff` though:

```
c("a", "b","a") %>% setdiff("a")
```